# Autohotkey .exe runs in XP, not in Win8

Tags: windows-8, windows-xp, autohotkey

I created an .exe using AutoHotKey.  I created it in Windows XP.  I've pushed it to some other users who are using later versions of Windows (Vista and/or 8).  The .exe is not working in their systems.  I don't see any activation of windows or any keystroke functions.
The .exe is opening windows and inputting keystrokes in XP.
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to run this in XP compatibility mode?

Comment: And of course, if you still have the original script, you could compile it again on the Vista/Windows 7/8 systems. Also try to see if running your exe in admin mode does help.

Comment: Last but not least, if you don't have the original script, you could try to reverse engineer the exe with [Exe2Ahk](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/Exe2Ahk.exe)

Answer (score 1):

You have to run AutoHotKey under the Administrator account. See explanation in this article, [AutoHotkey cannot interact with Windows 8 Windows…or can it!](http://geekswithblogs.net/deadlydog/archive/2012/09/10/autohotkey-cannot-interact-with-windows-8-windowshellipor-can-it.aspx)